# Create different sub-aggregations depending on a top-level filters aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a filters aggregation with ElasticSearch and within that aggregation I was wondering if I could create different sub-aggregations depending on the different filter buckets. In my case, I'm aggregating from two sources `chrome` and `electron`. For each source, I want to run different sub-aggregations. Below is my current aggregation hash:

```
aggs: {
  **top_level_agg,
  sources: {
    filters: {
      filters: {
        chrome: { term: { source: TrackingEvent::CHROME_SOURCE } },
        electron: { term: { source: TrackingEvent::ELECTRON_SOURCE } }
      }
    },
    aggs: {
      **chrome_specific_agg,
      **electron_specific_agg
    }
  }
}
```

This works but isn't ideal because the chrome and electron filters aggs results both contain the chrome specific and electron specific aggs. It would be better if I could do something like this (I know this doesn't work):

```
aggs: {
  **top_level_agg,
  sources: {
    filters: {
      filters: {
        chrome: { 
          term: { source: TrackingEvent::CHROME_SOURCE },
          aggs: {
            **chrome_specific_agg
          }
        },
        electron: { 
          term: { source: TrackingEvent::ELECTRON_SOURCE },
          aggs: {
            **electron_specific_agg
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with ES but I thought I'd ask. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Just gotta adjust the nested-ness a bit:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "top_level_agg": {},
    "chrome_specific_agg_name": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "source": "TrackingEvent::CHROME_SOURCE"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "chrome_specific_agg": {}
    },
    "electron_specific_agg_name": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "source": "TrackingEvent::ELECTRON_SOURCE"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "electron_specific_agg": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```